# How to add timer to a mobile app quiz using jQuery and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I have a small cross-platform mobile app, which is a quiz, and I want to add timer to the quiz. I have some initial code and it works kind of fine when you open it for the first time, but if you go back to a previous page and then again to forward to the page with the timer, the time passes so fast, it passes two seconds instead of one. I have the following code:

```
var timestamp;
var interval = 1;

function pad(n) { return ("0" + n).slice(-2); }

Number.prototype.pad = function (len) {
    return (new Array(len+1).join("0") + this).slice(-len);
}

timestamp = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

setInterval(function() {
        timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timestamp.getMinutes().pad(2) + ':' + timestamp.getSeconds().pad(2);
}, Math.abs(interval) * 1000);
```

I want it to be show only seconds and minutes in the format 01:10, which means 1 minute and 10 seconds. And as I said it works fine the first time, but if I go to the previous page and then again back to the current page with time, time passes in intervals of two seconds instead of one. I also want to show alert to the user if 1 hour passed, which I assume will be the maximum time allowed for the quiz. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I believe your problem is that the interval is initialised a second time and thus appears to be jumping 2 secs each time. Therefore, I propose setting a variable to determine if the timer has been initialised yet.

```
var initTimer = true;

$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(initTimer){
        setInterval(function() {
            timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timestamp.getMinutes().pad(2) + ':' + timestamp.getSeconds().pad(2);
        }, Math.abs(interval) * 1000);
        //timer has now been initialised so we now change the variable
        initTimer = false;
    }
});
```

You then just need an if statement within the setInterval function to check whether you're limit has being reached.

---

Occurs to me that I'm not sure if you want the timer reinitialised when returning to the page. In which case, within a `$(document).ready()` clear the timer, reset it and start it again.

```
var timer;
var timestamp = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$( document ).ready(function() {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    timestamp = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timestamp.getMinutes().pad(2) + ':' + timestamp.getSeconds().pad(2);
    }, Math.abs(interval) * 1000); 
});
```

Comment: Might not be perfectly there, but depends a little on how the rest of your code is setup. Hopefully enough to point you in the right direction though.